# stringWithContentsOfURL depreciated, help to update to 4.2?

Tags: ios4, nsstring, nsdata

Hello
Could anyone help me update this snippent to iOS 4.2:

```
-(void) whatever{
NSData *htmlData = [[NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString: @"http://www.objectgraph.com/contact.html"]] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
TFHpple *xpathParser = [[TFHpple alloc] initWithHTMLData:htmlData];
NSArray *elements  = [xpathParser search:@"//h3"]; // get the page title - this is xpath notation
TFHppleElement *element = [elements objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *myTitle = [element content];
NSLog(myTitle);
[xpathParser release];
[htmlData release];}
```

The only part that needs updating is below, you can effectivly forget the rest:

```
NSData *htmlData = [[NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:  @"http://www.objectgraph.com/contact.html"]] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

"stringWithContentsOfURL" has been deprechiated so what would be the updated version?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use

```
+ (id)stringWithContentsOfURL:(NSURL *)url encoding:(NSStringEncoding)enc error:(NSError **)error
```

And use it like that. Replace

```
NSData *htmlData = [[NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:  @"http://www.objectgraph.com/contact.html"]] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

by

```
NSData *htmlData = [[NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:  @"http://www.objectgraph.com/contact.html"]] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
```

Comment: I don't know how you ever wrote the code above if you don't know what the "+" means here... You should look at : http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#referencelibrary/GettingStarted/Learning_Objective-C_A_Primer/

Comment: excuse my ignorance, this is a slapdash application, how would i implement the above? i'm not well versed with objective c, just learning from examples.